# GetProcesses on local machine results in "Couldn't connect to remote machine."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In c#, I am using the following code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses("firefox.exe");
Console.WriteLine(processes.Length);
```

Which results in:

> InvalidOperationException: Couldn't connect to remote machine.

Notes:

- OS: Windows 7, 64-bit
- I am **not** attempting to connect to a remote machine.
- The Remote Registry service is set to **Auto** and is **started**

Any thoughts as to why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You have to use Process.GetProcessesByName() instead.

Comment: See this post once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655375/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-processes-running-on-a-local-virtual-machine

Comment: Both comments were relevant to the issue I was having, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8b2hzk8.aspx this call tries to connect to a computer names "firefox.exe" and retrieve the processes from there hence the exception.

EDIT:

Assuming you want to find all "firefox.exe" processes on the local machine you could

```
List<Process> ListOfFireFox = new List<Preocess>();
foreach (P in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if ( P.ProcessName.ToLower() == "firefox.exe" )
         ListOfFireFox.Add (P);
};

Console.WriteLine(ListOfFireFox.Count);
```

Answer (score 4):

You think you are specifying a process name, but you are actually specifying the machine name.

```
Process[] Process.GetProcesses(string machineName);
```

Hope this helps,
John

Answer (score 2):

Try this following code

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessByName("firefox.exe");
Console.WriteLine(processes.Length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the .exe

```
Process process = Process.GetProcess("firefox");
```

Comment: There is no such method as `Process.GetProcess()`.